# Working with two repos and two projects in Git

Tags: linux, git, github

I'm new to Git, and i want to push some files to one repo and other files to another repo, but when i do the second push it goes with the files of the first repo. How can i push the the files separately?

Comment: How do you keep the two repos separated? You would need two `.git` directories. Or do you mean two remotes?

Comment: `git` doesn't push *files*. It pushes *refs* (branch heads and/or tags), which point to commits, which happen to contain trees that reference blobs that represent the content of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should you have .git directories in each your project directories. And don't forget for use git bash inside directories what you want to push. Example:

1. Project A in
   C:/projectA
   inside projectA you have .git directories(hidden files)
2. Project B in
   C:/projectB
   inside projectB you have .git directories(hidden files)

for push project A, try this

> cd c: 
>   cd projectA

you stay in projectA, and then push.

Comment: Wow! I'm feeling such a newb! hahahahaha
Thank you so much!!! I created the Git folder on my Home folder!